# form from multiple models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I need to create a form where the rows are a list of users and the columns are all the user's permissions. The models are the default django User's and django Permission's models.

How can I do this things? Are there a way to do by django forms or I must do manually with django and js?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to view this data, extract the relevant information (User and Permission instances), and then generate a table using django templates. Django intentionally does not 'bless' any css or js frameworks, so you are required to do the html yourself (using tools of your choosing).

Forms aren't going to help you here I don't think. I advise you to draw up what it is you want to see, and start figuring out what the html is going to need to look like. Forms in django are simply a mechanism for passing data between django and the user. You are free to render them how you wish.